# javascript toggle?

Tags: javascript

I have written this javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function toggle(user_id) { 
    e=document.getElementById('toggleUserinfo_'+user_id); 
    a=document.getElementById('displayUserinfo_'+user_id); 
    if (e.style.display=='block') { 
      e.style.display='none'; a.innerHTML='show'; 
    } else { 
      e.style.display='block'; a.innerHTML='hide'; 
    } 
  } 
</script>
```

but its working fine on one page not working on other. The same file is used on both, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The chance is that in the other page the elements don't exist for example the "toggleUserInfo_" and "displayUserInfo_", check to see whether they are available or not.

Another problem that I see is "e" and "a" both the variables are global( missing var keyword ) which is not good.

Comment: By the way this type of toggling can cause trouble with inline elements, check this link : http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

Answer (score 0):

did you try by putting debugger; and debugging the code
and also if possible use === for comparison

If possible can you give more code to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

### Missing elements

It's highly likely that you don't have those two elements on the other page either.

```
toggleUserinfo_ID
toggleUserinfo_ID
```

ID being user_id.

### Use Firbug

When having Javascript problems, majority of web developers use Firefox with **Firebug** extension that alows you to set breakpoints and debug the whole javascript functionality of the page.

Set a breakpoint on the first lone of your `toggle` function and see what's going on.